# How can reserved keyword 'clone' in PHP 5 function be made compatible with PHP 7?

Tags: php, keyword

A PHP 7 compatibility check pointed out two errors in some PHP 5 code that is not compatible with PHP 7.

> 'clone' is a reserved keyword introduced in PHP version 5.0 and
>   cannot be invoked as a function (T_CLONE)

How can the following code be fixed so it is compatible with PHP 7?

```
/**
 * Implements {@link aCssMinifierFilter::filter()}.
 *
 * @param array $tokens Array of objects of type aCssToken
 * @return integer Count of added, changed or removed tokens; a return value larger than 0 will rebuild the array
 */
public function apply(array &$tokens)
    {
    $r = 0;
    $transformations = array("-moz-keyframes", "-webkit-keyframes");
    for ($i = 0, $l = count($tokens); $i < $l; $i++)
        {
        if (get_class($tokens[$i]) === "CssAtKeyframesStartToken")
            {
            for ($ii = $i; $ii < $l; $ii++)
                {
                if (get_class($tokens[$ii]) === "CssAtKeyframesEndToken")
                    {
                    break;
                    }
                }
            if (get_class($tokens[$ii]) === "CssAtKeyframesEndToken")
                {
                $add    = array();
                $source = array();
                for ($iii = $i; $iii <= $ii; $iii++)
                    {
                    $source[] = clone($tokens[$iii]);
                    }
                foreach ($transformations as $transformation)
                    {
                    $t = array();
                    foreach ($source as $token)
                        {
                        $t[] = clone($token);
                        }
                    $t[0]->AtRuleName = $transformation;
                    $add = array_merge($add, $t);
                    }
                if (isset($this->configuration["RemoveSource"]) && $this->configuration["RemoveSource"] === true)
                    {
                    array_splice($tokens, $i, $ii - $i + 1, $add);
                    }
                else
                    {
                    array_splice($tokens, $ii + 1, 0, $add);
                    }
                $l = count($tokens);
                $i = $ii + count($add);
                $r += count($add);
                }
            }
        }
    return $r;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any function name `clone()` in your project?? or is it php built in `clone`??

Comment: rename `clone` to something else

Comment: `$source[] = clone($tokens[$iii]);` < *ahem* @Sohel0415

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner its a call to clone function, i asked if there is any function defined with the name `clone()`

Comment: @Sohel0415 heh, my mistake. It's late; I think I best hang it up for tonight.

Comment: @Sohel0415 No there is no clone() function.

Comment: then just use a space when use clone and make sure its a clonable object `$source[] = clone $tokens[$iii];`

Comment: Why did this question get a down vote?

Comment: @Sohel0415 Thanks for instruction. I'll do that.

Comment: "A PHP 7 compatibility check pointed out [...]". Well, *which* one? That's not an actual syntax error in 7.x. Clone might be a language construct, but can very much still be used with parens and in expression context `var_dump(clone(clone(clone($obj))));`

Comment: @mario Which one? SiteGround’s PHP 7 compatibility checker with WordPress 4.9.4 installed, which is probably the PHP Compatibility Checker (WP Engine). I found a more detailed answer elsewhere: It’s because clone is a keyword, not a function, therefore:
clone( $date ) ❌
clone $date 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the code is trying to clone an object. But, you  have parentheses around the method.

The code should read

```
$t[] = clone $token;
```

`clone` isn't a function per se, it's a function that calls an object's `__clone` method

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This worked for me. Delete the parens that marked clone as a function so it is treated as a Keyword.  In line 3346 change:
    `$source[] = clone($tokens[$iii]);`
to:
    `$source[] = clone $tokens[$iii];`

In line 3353 change:
    `$t[] = clone($token);`
to:
    `$t[] = clone $token;`